# C# Object is read-only when assign certificate

Tags: c#, wsdl, certificate

I'm trying to call web service provided by WSDL file.

after adding the WSDL as service referece and point to location of WSDL file on my computer.

using code i tried to assign a certificate to the web service like this:

```
   NeqatyService.NeqatyWSAPIPortTypeClient mPortType = new NeqatyWSAPIPortTypeClient();

  Byte[] rawData = File.ReadAllBytes(@"c:\cert.p12");
                String cert64 = Convert.ToBase64String(rawData);
                X509Certificate2 certificates = new X509Certificate2(rawData, "pass", X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable | X509KeyStorageFlags.PersistKeySet | X509KeyStorageFlags.UserKeySet);
                mPortType.ClientCredentials.ClientCertificate.Certificate = certificates;
```

the debugger raise an error on this line:

```
mPortType.ClientCredentials.ClientCertificate.Certificate = certificates;
```

telling that:
Object is read-only

I want to notice that, i used to call the web service using SOAPUI 
providing the certificate and the password and it worked.

can anybody help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

Try modifying the value of messageEncoding to "Mtom" in the binding configuration.  Here is an example of a configuration that I used recently.  I was getting that error when the value was set to "Text."

```
            <binding name="AWDProcessingServiceBinding" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
                openTimeout="00:10:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
                allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                maxBufferSize="655360" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="655360"
                messageEncoding="Mtom" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
                useDefaultWebProxy="true">
                <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
                    maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
                <security mode="Transport">
                    <transport clientCredentialType="Certificate" proxyCredentialType="Basic"
                        realm="" />
                    <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
                </security>
            </binding>
```